# Javascript get mousemove clientX value on html progress tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

i need to get full working video progresbar

there is code:

## html

```
<video class="video" width="612" height="350" preload="none" controls controlsList="nodownload" oncontextmenu="return false;">
    <source src="video.php?id=1" type="video/mp4">
</video>


<div class="controls">
    <button>play</button>
    <button>pause</button>
    <button>fullscreen</button>
    <button>widescreen</button> 
    <progress class="pbar" value="0" min="0" max="100"></progress>
</div>
```

## js

```
let video = document.querySelector('.video');
let progressBar = document.querySelector('.pbar');

video.addEventListener('timeupdate', ()=>
{
    var percentage = Math.floor((100 / video.duration)*video.currentTime);
    progressBar.value = percentage;
    progressBar.innerHTML = percentage + "% played";
}
);


progressBar.addEventListener('mousemove', ()=>
{
    console.log(progressBar.clientX);
}
);
```

to simple explain i need to get clientX or clienY value from progress tag on mousemove, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the examples in the [mousemove documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event), it's the event object provided to the callback which contains the X and Y values, not the element itself. This should help you:

```
progressBar.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY);
});
```